# errno NOT being set to ERANGE after converting a string with a HUGE number to a double floating point number using strtod() in C

Tags: c

I am perplexed that errno is *not* being set to `ERANGE` after `strtod()` tries to convert a string with a huge real number to an double floating point number.

Here is what happens when I run my code:

```
Enter a real number: 5656565656565652622326352635236523652362356235
You entered 5656565656565652358969982685269310483757793280.000000.
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int getDouble(char* prompt, double* doubleRealNumber);

int main(void)
{  
    double d;

    getDouble("Enter a real number: ", &d);
    printf("You entered %lf.\n", d);

    return 0;
}

int getDouble(char* prompt, double* doubleRealNumber)
{
    int const MAXBUFSIZE = 1024;
    char buf[MAXBUFSIZE]; // use 1KiB just to be sure
    int success; // flag for successful conversion
    
    do
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
        
        if (!fgets(buf, MAXBUFSIZE, stdin))
        {
            // reading input failed:
            return 1;
        }
        
        // have some input, convert it to integer:
        char *endptr;
        
        errno = 0; // reset error number
    
        *doubleRealNumber = strtod(buf, &endptr);
        
        if (errno == ERANGE)
        {
            printf("Sorry, this number is too small or too large.\n");
            success = 0;
        }
        else if (endptr == buf)
        {
            // no character was read
            success = 0;
        }
        else if (*endptr && *endptr != '\n')
        {
            // *endptr is neither end of string nor newline,
            // so we didn't convert the *whole* input
            success = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            success = 1;
        }
    } while (!success); // repeat until we got a valid real number
    
    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to be "out of range"?

Comment: That looks like a loss of precision rather than out of range. Not every number within the dynamic range (of the exponent) can be accurately represented (by the mantissa).

Comment: Try with this input: `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: As a general comment, you should not use the value of ```errno``` before checking whether the return value of the function indicates that ```errno``` is meaningful. You may be relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: That's a good point - you're only supposed to examine `errno` if `HUGE_VAL` is returned.

Comment: The range of `double` is `1.7E-308` to `1.7E+308`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  Yes, when I entered 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, I get the message "Sorry, this number is too small or too large."  So the code does work.  I did not realize that the conversion could cause a loss of precision.

Comment: Whenever I try  to use HUGE_VAL, the compiler complains it is not declared. e.g. this code does not work -- if ((*doubleRealNumber == HUGE_VAL) && (errno == ERANGE)) etc etc

Comment: You need to include `math.h`

Comment: @sj95126 https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtod.html states that `errno` is not changed if the conversion was successful, so if `errno` is set to 0 prior to the call to `strtod`, you can simply check for `errno`, if the conversion was successful, `errno`will still be 0.

Comment: Thanks Jabberwocky.  Adding math.h did the trick.  I suspect my code will always work.  To to be safe, the if statement in my code could be changed to:  if (((*doubleRealNumber == HUGE_VAL) || (*doubleRealNumber == -HUGE_VAL)) && (errno == ERANGE)) etc etc

Comment: @RobK actually no, you don't need `HUGE_VAL`, read my previous comment. `errno !=  0)` is enough. If it's 0 then the conversion was successful.

Comment: @Jabberwocky -- Thanks.  I may add a "if (errno != 0)" check to be on the safe side.  But it is my understanding that strtod() only sets the errno to ERANGE if there is a problem.  So checking errno for other values may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errno is in fact being set properly to ERANGE when a very large (or very small) number is entered.

If one enters a really big number like "100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", errno is set to ERANGE and the following is printed -- "Sorry, this number is too small or too large."  So, the code posted is valid and works properly.

The reason is the input number and the output number do not match in the question is due to a loss of precision rather than out of range.
Not every number within the dynamic range (of the exponent) can be accurately represented (by the mantissa).

Many thanks to Useless and Jabberwocky for pointing this out!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that whether ```errno``` is set to ```ERANGE``` on underflow is implementation-defined.